# How to catch keyboard input without visible input field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, text, input, cordova

Situation:

- HTML5 with jQuery Mobile on iPad (**EDIT**: HTML5 page in a PhoneGap app)
- external keyboard attached
- text input field is hidden, no visible input field
- no focus on text input field -> no soft keyboard shown

Goal:

- catch keyboard input without showing & focusing on a text input field
- Keyboard input is are variable phrases (e.g. name1, object2, phrase3)
- Just start typing and the page should capture that typing

--> How can I detect the keyboard input into the hidden input field?

I know the keydown / keypress / keyup events, however they seem to require a visible input field

Comment: `$(document).on('keyup', $.mobile.pageContainer, function() { });` try it. or `$('body').on('keyup', function () { });`

Comment: here's a working example. If this is what you need, let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sG9n8/

Comment: For me, both statements & the answer below make it work only with focus on the input field - but if the input field is hidden, no keyboard input in captured. any pitfalls I overlooked?

Comment: Check the demo I made.

Comment: Demo works on nicely on Desktop Safari, but not in Mobile Safari though. Will dig deeper in some hours.

Comment: Then bind it to `$.mobile.pageContainer`

Comment: On the iPad (& a PhoneGap app container) all options do only work within a selected text field with visible soft keyboard, not everywhere in the page. Just edited the question to further clarify that the HTML5 page as well lives in a PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the event to the document like this:-

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply position the element off-canvas, without needing to alter its DOM/CSS visibility state.

```
<style> .inputValue{position:absolute;left:-99999px} </style>
<input type="text" class="inputValue" autofocus="autofocus"/>
```

And then at any given point when you require the input's value you call the below script.

```
<script> $('.inputValue').val(); </script>
```